# Not getting complete data

Tags: android, json

I want to get JSON from [this URL](http://holit.ir/app.php?last&page=1&catid=1&kind=0) but because the JSON is large, the server load the JSON slowly.
I get JSON from web by this code:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        if (params != null)
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        Log.i("TAG", sb.toString());
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

But I can just get first part as JSON and my JSON remains incomplete
please help me.

Comment: Are you sure this is your valid json response?

Comment: Logcat may fail to print large messages fully.. you can try with system.out.print(message).

Comment: @Alireza its coming in multiple Lines(with '\n') so eclipse will not display whole data in a single time

Comment: This is not a correct json , i just checked it on jsonlint.com

Comment: @cafebabe1991 as it is coming with '\n' to make this JSON correct He must need to remove '\n' from the Response String. then it will be Correct JSOn.

Comment: @SilentKiller Ya and moreover as i can see that the basic syntax of json has not been followed.No semi colon ,Arrays have not been used correctly and much more.It seems to a total mess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            if (params != null)
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            json = getResponseBody(httpEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jObj;

    }
```

**Add this Method**

```
public String getResponseBody(final HttpEntity entity) throws IOException, ParseException {

        if (entity == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity may not be null");
        }

        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

        if (instream == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (entity.getContentLength() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(

            "HTTP entity too large to be buffered in memory");
        }

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, HTTP.UTF_8));

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

        } finally {
            instream.close();
            reader.close();
        }
        return buffer.toString();

    }
```